# Custom Paint handler on a WinForms Control inside a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, paint

I have a WPF application with a Windows Form element hosted inside it, using this method:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
    new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

gMapZoom = new GMap();
gMapZoom.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(gMapZoom_Paint);
host.Child = gMapZoom; // gMapZoom is the Windows Form control
// Add the interop host control to the Grid
// control's collection of child controls.
this.grid1.Children.Add(host);
```

However, I'm having problems trying to add a custom Paint event handler to it. It seems that adding it in WPF (not shown here) causes the drawing to be done beneath the WinForm control, so nothing appears on top. Adding it to the WinForm control does nothing whatsoever; the paint event (gMapZoom_Paint) is never even called.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a PaintEventHandler event to your Windows Form Control (gMapZoom)

```
 public event PaintEventHandler OnPaint;

 public GMap()
 {
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(GMap_Paint);
 }

 void Gmap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     OnPaint(this, e);
 }
```

In WPF code behind:

```
{
  System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
                new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

  gmap = new GMap();
  gmap.OnPaint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(gmap_Paint);
  host.Child = gmap;
  this.grid1.Children.Add(host);
 }

void gmap_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
  //Custom paint         
}
```

Then you can trigger the OnPaint event by:

```
gmap.Invalidate();
```

Comment: That doesn't really help.. that's what I'm already doing.  The problem is that the paint event is never being called.  Like, in your example, GMap_Paint never gets executed.

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean: http://pastebin.com/HEqW08Rs

In that example, the pictureBox_Paint method is called once, when the application first loads.  After that, even when Invalidate() is called, it doesn't repaint.

Comment: hmmm... I have made the answer clearer.  It is working in my sandbox.

Comment: I figured out my issue: the Invalidate() was never being called in the first place.  Turns out any event handlers you put in have to be handlers for the WinForms control, not the WPF control that contains it.  So in my example above, I had to add the event handlers to pictureBox, rather than grid1.  Thanks for your help! :)