# Paint event does not fire when Invalidate() is called

Tags: c#, wpf, events, paintevent

I am working on a WPF application that has a Panel within a `WindowsFormHost`. The panel contains graphics that need to be redrawn every so often, and the code that draws these graphics is located within an `OnPaint()` event. The problem is, the `OnPaint()` event never seems to fire. To debug, I added a button to my form and used the button's click event handler to call the Invalidate() event. Even when I call `Invalidate()`, I can't seem to get the Paint event to fire. My code-behind looks like this:

```
public MainWindow() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void myPanel_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    /// Draw stuff
} 

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myPanel.Invalidate();
}
```

And my XAML looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel">
        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="windowsFormsHost" >
            <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                <wf:Panel x:Name="myPanel" Paint="myPanel_Paint"/>
            </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I've read through this: [WindowsFormHost Paint Event Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118173/windowsformhost-paint-event-not-firing)

...but we don't seem to be having the same problem, as my XAML does reference my Paint event handler, and `OnPaint()` still doesn't fire.

I have already tried adding `myPanel.Update()` to my `Button_Click` event, beneath my call to `myPanel.Invalidate()`. That also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible that `Invalidate()` is not really invalidating?

Comment: Works just fine.  It will probably help if you can actually *see* the panel, set the host's Height to, say, 200.  And you'll have to use the Random class in the Paint event handler to actually see a difference.

Comment: This question might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198298/custom-paint-handler-on-a-winforms-control-inside-a-wpf-application